# Rails association to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's say I have 2 tables:

```
Users
user_id name

Tags
tagger_id tagged_id
```

This describes a situation where you can

And the models that I'm trying to set up are:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags, :foreign_key => "tagger_id"
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tagger, :class => "User"
    belongs_to :tagged, :class => "User"
end
```

I'm trying to set it up so that when I do:

```
user.tags
```

It comes back with a list of User objects.  With my current setup, it comes back with just the actual Tag record with ids instead of objects.  How do I set it up so it returns a list of User objects?

I tried using:

```
has_many :tags, :foreign_key => "tagger_id", :source => :tagged
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: `user.tags` is supposed to give you Tags, not Users... You're telling it "Give me all the tags for this user". Can you clarify what exact list of users you're expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for has_many :through.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :tags, :foreign_key => "tagger_id"
    has_many :tagged, :through => :tags
end
```

Then `user.tagged` should give you the list of users you want.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy. Is there any way to reclaim the "tags" name instead so I can use user.tags instead of user.tagged for it? Has a better ring to it :)

Comment: I'd agree with Max - tags are tags, not users. If you want, you could probably define a "tags" method, but I really don't see the point.